# Check for Background in CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have a number of CSS attributes and Classes which get applied based on where the element appears in the HTML.

However some elements do not equal any of these values so i want to be able to check which elements in a DIV do not have a background set via CSS then apply a background.

Something like:

```
$('.divclass:has('background')').addClass('IneedaBG.gif');
```

Or

```
$('.divclass:has(not:class1,class2,class2)').addClass('IneedaBG.gif');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure class names can have a dot (IneedaBG.gif). Imagine if you tried to select this with a selector:

```
$(".IneedaBG.gif")
```

I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work. Is it possible you want a CSS class with the image defined in the properties?

Also, you can speed up your selector performance a little, as direct reference to the .divclass class will scan the whole DOM:

```
$("div.divclass:has('background')").addClass("IneedaBG");
```

Try also using " for the selectors, instead of having multiple '

Can you have an ID for the DIV? That would be even better!

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering out elements that don't have a background set (either in stylesheets or inline, jquery catches both), then add your class to just those elements:

```
$('.divclass')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).css('background-image') })
    .addClass('IneedaBG')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.divclass').each(function()
{
    if($(this).css('background') != '') $(this).addClass('Bgclass');
});
```

Your code

```
$('.divclass:has('background')').addClass('IneedaBG.gif');
```

Will not work: just look at the color highlighting. The inner quotes need to be `""` or ``` `` ```. Also `:has` is for elements containg elements: `a:has(b)` means "Select all `a` elements containing at least one `b` element"